# Strongswan traffic between tunnels

Tags: networking, vpn, tunnel

I have a strongswan machine which is used to establish multiple ipsec tunnels to our live sites.
We have also a tunnel established to our main office.
I would like that our office's subnet is able to get on a specific live site, passing through the strongswan server....so basically traffic coming from a tunnel and go to another one.

```
conn Live
   authby=secret
   auto=start
   ike=aes256-sha1;modp1024
   keyexchange=ike
   phase2=esp
   phase2alg=aes256-sha1;modp1024
   compress=no
   pfs=no
   type=tunnel

   left=publicip
   leftid=publicip
   leftsubnet=172.19.0.0/24
   leftsourceip=172.19.0.1
   leftnexthop=%defaultroute

conn OFFICE
        also=Live
        right=publicip
        rightsubnet=192.168.40.0/24


conn LIVESITE
        also=Live
        right=publicip
        rightsubnet=10.153.0.0/16
```

I want traffic coming from 192.168.40.0/24 to be able to reach 10.153.0.0/16, but I assume it have to be natted as 172.19.0.0/24
And this is where I'm struggling to :-/

Answer (score 0):

A NAT won't automatically fix this issue. The problem is that the negotiated IPsec policies with the two remote peers will only allow traffic addressed to `172.19.0.0/24` to be sent to the strongSwan server.

So even if you NAT traffic from `192.168.40.0/24` to an IP in `172.19.0.0/24` that won't change a thing, because traffic to `10.153.0.0/16` won't be sent through the "OFFICE" tunnel in the first place.

One possible fix is to negotiate appropriate IPsec policies that allow traffic to the respective remote subnet to pass via strongSwan server. This requires config changes on all involved IPsec hosts (at least if bidirectional connectivity is required, see at the bottom for an asymmetric variation).

On the strongSwan side, and if you are using IKEv2 and the peer's implementations supports it, you could simply extend *leftsubnet*:

```
conn OFFICE
    also=Live
    right=publicip
    leftsubnet=172.19.0.0/24,10.153.0.0/16
    rightsubnet=192.168.40.0/24


conn LIVESITE
    also=Live
    right=publicip
    leftsubnet=172.19.0.0/24,192.168.40.0/24
    rightsubnet=10.153.0.0/16
```

However, with IKEv1 (and some IKEv2 implementations) it is necessary to negotiate separate IPsec SAs for each combination of local and remote subnet. So the configuration would look like this:

```
conn OFFICE-local
    also=Live
    right=publicip
    rightsubnet=192.168.40.0/24

conn OFFICE-live
     also=OFFICE-local
     leftsubnet=10.153.0.0/16

conn LIVESITE-local
    also=Live
    right=publicip
    rightsubnet=10.153.0.0/16

conn LIVESITE-office
     also=LIVESITE-local
     leftsubnet=192.168.40.0/24
```

The configurations of the remote hosts has to be changed accordingly.

If you don't need bidirectional connectivity (e.g. if hosts in `192.168.40.0/24` must be able to connect to hosts in `192.168.40.0/24` but not vice-versa), you could also only change one side (the "OFFICE" connection in this case) and then NAT packets to a local IP to match the existing IPsec policies of the other connection.